# Why passing down a Command object won't work?

Tags: java, gwt

I wonder why passing a `Command` object two-level down of a parent-child class won't work.

Like this (Class A is parent of B and B is parent of C):

```
Class A (Creates the instance of the Command object that is passed down to B)

+-- Class B ( Pass down the object to C) 


+------- Class C ( Callsthe execute() method of the Command object)
```

Whereas, when the instance of the Command object is created in Class B and the passed down to class C it works fine.

Example:

EDIT:

Example (Hand-written code):

```
public class A {
   private Command command;
   private B b;
   public A() {
     b = new B();
     command = new Command() {
          public void execute() {
            // Do something
          }
     }
     b.setCommand(command);
   }

public class B {
   private Command command;
   private C c;

   public B() {
     c = new C();
     c.setCommand(this.command);
   }

   public void setCommand(Command command){
       this.command = command; 
   }  

}


public class C {
   private Command command;
   public C() {

   }

   public void doStuff() {
       command.execute();
   }
   public void setCommand(Command command){
       this.command = command; 
   }        
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your diagram means - showing code would make it a lot clearer, ideally in a short but complete example, as far as is practical.

Comment: Class A is parent of B and B is parent of C.

Comment: And can you clarify what "won't work" means? What happens when you execute it? Note that there's no inheritance involved here, contrary to the implication of "parent-child" here.

Comment: That says what *doesn't* happen - but what *does* happen? And why have you now removed the code which explained your question far better than the existing text?

Comment: Nope I did not removed it, I just edited it to better reflect the problematic code.

Comment: The problem was with Class B.

Comment: You did remove it, in edit 3. Good to see it's back again, this time making it clear where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that during the process of passing down, the Command object from Class A is assigned to local Command object of Class B, which is the local Command object of Class B is sent to Class C.

Comment: So in other words the object is like "buffered" in the middle. It works now since what I did is just to make sure that Class B just pass down the Object to C without modification.

Answer (score 2):

From your sample code, it's obvious that by the time you call c.setCommand() (in the constructor of B) the this.command hasn't yet been updated with the Command instance passed from A:

```
b = new B();
// here, c.setCommand() has already been called with b.command, which hasn't been initialized, so is 'null'
b.setCommand(command); // sets b.command, but doesn't change c.command's value, which is then still 'null'
```

Stepping through the code with a debugger would have revealed the source of bug in a few seconds. This is Java 101.

Comment: Yah, however the code I posted here is used with a Java-to-Javascript compiler, so debugging is not that easy.

Comment: Debugging in GWT is as easy as in any other environment, at least when the bug is in your Java code: run your code in DevMode so the Java code runs (no translation to JS), and step through with any Java debugger. In Eclipse: Debug As… → Web Application.

Answer (score 1):

Is the access modifier of the Command object public?

Answer (score 0):

Oooo ... you need further education on the sequence of object instantiation.

- You instantiated B object.
- Then within instantiation of C object, you assign C object the command of B object.
- Which at that moment the command is null.
- Then only you assigned B object a command, which is too late because you should have passed the command into the constructor of B.

Class A:

```
public class A {
   private B b;
   public A() {
     b = new B(
       new Command() {
         public void execute() {
           Window.alert("Gotcha");
         }
       }
     );
   }
```

Class B:

```
public class B {
   private C c;

   public B(Command cmd) {
     c = new C();
     c.setCommand(cmd);
     c.doStuff();
   }
}
```

Class C:

```
public class C {
  private Command command;
  public C() {
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    command.execute();
  }

  public void setCommand(Command command){
    this.command = command; 
  }        
}
```

Or, why not this

```
public class B {
   private C c;

   public B(Command cmd) {
     c = new C(cmd).doStuff(1000);
   }
}

public class C {
  private Command command;
  public C(Command cmd) {
    this.command = cmd; 
  }

  public C doStuff(int i) {
    if (--i>0){
      new C(cmd).doStuff(i);
    }    
    command.execute();
    return this;
  }
}
```